# Appending 5 text files columnwise

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, append, multiple-columns

I want to add all lines of 4 text files and have an output file with 5 columns. one of my files has two columns. I have tryed to do it with csv.reader, but I am not able to get the correct result. At this moment I am working on this code:

```
from os import walk
import csv
mypath = 'C:\\Users\\files to append'     
o_data = []
files = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mypath):
    files.extend(filenames)
    break
print(files)
for afile in files:
    file_h=open(afile)
    a_list = []
    a_list.append(file_h.read())
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_h, delimiter = ' ')
    for row in csv_reader:
        a_list.append(row[0])
    o_data.append((n for n in a_list))
    file_h.close()

with open('output.dat', 'w') as op_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(op_file, delimiter = ' ')
    for row in list(zip(*o_data)):
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

my five text files look like this  with differnt values:

```
SCALAR
ND   9418
ST  0
TS     45000.34
0.0000
100.02
```

the result should be like this ( 4 headers and 5 number of columns):

```
SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR  
ND   9418 ND   9418 ND   9418 ND   9418 
ST  0 ST  0 ST  0 ST  0 ST  0 
TS 45000.34 TS 45000.34 TS 45000.34 TS 45000.34 
0.0000 1.0000 2.4344 4.5656 81.2123
100.02 123.32 333.85 435.33 987.11
```

I would appreciate any suggustion.

**Attempt 2**

I tryed to rewrite it in other way. So this is my solution, but it does not work properly. I cannot understand why it cannot rename the "output1.out" to "output.out"

This is the code:

import os

"""
Please put all the bnecessary data into the directory 
"""

```
f = []
for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Append'):
    if file.endswith(".dat"):
        f.append(file)
        print(file)
        os.rename(file,"input.dat")
        file = file.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
        print(file)
        with open("output.out", "r") as textfile1, open("input.dat", "r") as textfile2,\
             open("output1.out", "w") as out:
            for x, y in zip(textfile1, textfile2):
                x = x.strip()
                y = y.strip()
                print("{0} {1}".format(x, y), file = out)
                print(fname)
         os.rename("input.dat", file+".txt")
    os.rename("output1.out", "output.out" )
print(f) # just for checking
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you are looking for. Rather than using `os.walk()` it uses `glob.glob()` to get a suitable list of files, e.g. `*.dat` for all dat files, or you could use `i*.dat` depending on your file names.

It reads each file into a `data` list and then uses the `zip(*data)` trick to read the rows of columns as columns of rows. With these it then combines each of the lists for each row into a single list using `chain.from_iterable()` and writes this out to the output CSV file with spaces as delimiters.

```
from itertools import chain
import glob
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=' ')
    data = []

    for filename in glob.glob('c*.txt'):
        with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
            csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
            data.append(list(csv_input))

    for row in zip(*data):
        csv_output.writerow(chain.from_iterable(row))
```

Giving you something like:

```
SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR
ND 9418 ND 9419 ND 9420 ND 9421 ND 9422
ST 0 ST 1 ST 2 ST 3 ST 4
TS 45000.34 TS 45000.35 TS 45000.36 TS 45000.37 TS 45000.38
0.0000 0.0001 0.0002 0.0003 0.0004
100.02 100.03 100.04 100.05 100.06
```

Comment: it gives an erorr:     csv_output.writerow(chain.from_iterable(row))

Error: sequence expected

Comment: It might depend on your Python version, try `csv_output.writerow(list(chain.from_iterable(row)))`

Comment: Excellent! Glad it works for you. Don't forget to click on the grey tick (under the up/down arrows) to select the answer as the accepted solution.